# CMake configuration to build the c# project?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, cmake

My project is having c, cpp,c# files on different modules.I am trying to build the entire project with cmake.I am able to compile the c,cpp files with CMakeLists configurations, but I have problem with compiling c# files with CMakeLists configuration.

I am not clear how to write the CMakeLists.txt file for C# projects. Is that cmake supports the c# projects or not ?. If cmake supports csharp please provide sample CMakeLists.txt if any.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?! and how would you manage all the non-cs info in the csproj file e.g. references, resources, templates...

Comment: I would like to cross compile my entire project with cmake.

Comment: I need to build the project in linux as well as windows environment.Build any project in both linux and windows is possible with cmake.

Comment: Use Mono. - You should use the right tool for each problem.

Comment: To clarify, CMake 3.8 and greater now fully supports the C# language. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55420842/3987854) on your other question has an example.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, have very little experience with CMake, but look at [this one](https://github.com/SimpleITK/SimpleITK/tree/master/CMake). As I understand they have a codebase similar to yours.

Also, see [this](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/C-NET-td7542328.html) discussion. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074144/generate-c-sharp-project-using-cmake/2075828#2075828).